# Error while sending an email in Lambda (python) due to smtp

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, smtp

I have the following code in a lambda:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    msg_email = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg_email.attach(MIMEText("mymessage", 'plain'))
    msg_email['Subject'] = subject
    msg_email['From'] = "from@mail.com"
    msg_email['To'] = "to@mail.com"
    try:
        print("AAAA")
        with smtplib.SMTP('email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', 587) as smtp_server:
            print("BBBB")
            smtp_server.ehlo()
            smtp_server.starttls()
            smtp_server.ehlo()
            smtp_server.login('myid', 'mypass')
            smtp_server.sendmail("from@mail.com", "to@mail.com", msg_email.as_string())
    except Exception:
        print("Couldn't send message.")
        raise
    else:
        print("Email sent!")
```

This code prints "AAAA", but before printing "BBBB" I get an error executing the lambda: Task timed out after 3.01 seconds. However, if I run it in my EC2 instance works fine. Why lambda cannot execute it?

**EDIT**: The role of the lambda has these permissions: AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole(with some uiid after it), pinpoint-email-ers-, AmazonSESFullAccess, AmazonWorkMailFullAccess, AmazonWorkMailMessageFlowFullAccess

Comment: Is lambda perhaps in a VPC?

Comment: in the same as the ec2. Actually, it's security group has inbound and outbound with all traffic at 0.0.0.0/0 open. It has a layer to add some libraries. Could that affect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda in a VPC **does not have internet connection** if you place it in a public subnet. It must be placed in a **private subnet**, which has route table with routes pointing to a [NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html). The NAT will be placed in the public subnet.

The details are described in AWS Docs:

- [How do I give internet access to a Lambda function that's connected to an Amazon VPC?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/)

Alternatively, just don't place your lambda in a VPC if you don't have to.